# Beckhoff Ethercat slaves memory

Tags: memory, io, ethernet, ethercat

I'm currently working on Beckhoff slaves, and i wanted to know if it exist files which describe the memory of the slave in relation to their type (EL1014, EL2622, ...). I need these files because I want to create a slave stack.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly I can't really tell what you are after.  The ethercat spec is defined in [documents](http://www.beckhoff.com/english.asp?download/ethercat.htm?id=35572044440) on Beckhoff's site.  That would define the standard registers and their meanings.  You'll probably need to be a registered to download anything though.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.beckhoff.com/english/download/ethercat_development_products.htm?id=17746621196344) the page with the links to the Slave device register definitions document.